# What is the benefit of using V.A.T.S.?

Tags: fallout-4

Throughout my playthrough of Fallout 4, I've never once felt the need to use VATS. I never even considered using it since my understanding of it is that it's just letting the game do the shooting or hitting for you and you're leaving it up to RNG to win a battle.

The only reason I see to use V.A.T.S. is for the critical hits (assuming that criticals only occur through VATS outside of sneak attacks) and for determining if a distant NPC is friend or foe.

What are (if any) the other reasons to use V.A.T.S.?

Comment: Do you not think it's cool to blow off enemy body parts in slow motion? ;) Seriously though, I would consider the "cool factor" to be a benefit.

Comment: Haha i do admit it is cool, just sadly not much else to it aside from what i've already mentioned :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The **V**ault-**T**ec **A**ssisted **T**argetting **S**ystem first appeared in Fallout 3, and was both inspired and adapted from the combat mechanics of the original Fallout and Fallout 2. The original games were entirely turn based, which differs greatly from the current generation of first person shooter titles that Bethesda make. A main influence in including VATS was the ability to play Fallout 3 with out any skill in first person shooters, which hardcore fans may not necessarily have had. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Primarily, this gives you the benefit of a **Turn-Based Strategy Approach**. However, there are many other benefits to using VATS, both intentional and unintentional. These benefits include **Critical Hits**, **Threat Detection**, and the aesthetic **Cinematic Combat**. There are also **V.A.T.S. Specific Perks** that provide benefits when particular actions are performed in V.A.T.S., both to improve your combat ability, and include additional function.

### Turn-Based Strategy Approach

The primary function of V.A.T.S. is to provide a turn-based approach to combat. In V.A.T.S., Fallout 4 drops into slow motion. During this time, you can choose specific body parts, on specific enemies. Each body part will display the percentage chance to hit, and when highlighted, will reflect the approximate damage you would cause on the enemies health bar.

This allows you to tactically plan out your attack. You can see your exact chances of landing a critical head shot. You can see how much damage your current weapon will land on the target, which gives you a good feel for enemy resistances to specific target areas, or from specific weapons. You should also keep in mind that guns tend to allow targeting specific parts of the enemy, where as melee and thrown weapons will only let you target the enemy.

This can be especially helpful at times where you wish to hit a specific part on the enemy for strategical reason. For example, a good shot to a ghouls leg will blow it straight off. The ghoul might still be at half health, but with the leg gone, the fight becomes a lot easier. As another example, you can target a grenade or explosive, either on an enemies belt or as it is being thrown. This can make for an easy way to dispatch of a group of enemies.

**You can perform the same shots in real time, V.A.T.S. just makes it easier**. You will also receive a 90% damage resistance, as with previous games. The damage reduction can be hard to make use of, due to the game moving in slow motion, but a quick hand can open V.A.T.S. as your player character is about to take a nasty hit, allowing a fair amount of the damage to absorb into V.A.T.S.

Keep in mind that to rely on V.A.T.S. constantly, you want to favor your agility stat and AP maximization. The higher your agility, the higher the weapon hit chances, and the more AP you have, the more shots you can fire off. AP is more directly impacted by a variety of things, including your weight, and your equipped weapon. There are a few consumables you can take to both replenish and temporarily increase it, and the actions of both running and melee attacking drains it regardless of if you are in V.A.T.S.

### Critical Hits

V.A.T.S not only lets you slow down time to fight the enemy in a strategic sense, but it also gives you the great benefit of critical hits.

Whenever you hit an enemy in V.A.T.S, your critical hit metre fills up. When your critical metre is full, you can hit the reload button to execute an automatic critical, in V.A.T.S. This guarantees a critical hit, which can be used to strategically blow a limb off a difficult enemy, or perform a high damage head shot at a distance normally difficult without luck and skill.

This ability is directly influenced by Luck. Luck not only determines how quickly you fill the metre, but you can unlock a perk that allows you to "bank" your critical hits. This allows you to execute several critical shots in one go, where normally you can only hold a single critical shot at a time.

### Threat Detection

This tactic comes from previous Fallout titles, and may reduce the experience of the game as it was intended.

V.A.T.S is designed to allow you to assess the enemy, and attack accordingly. As a result, V.A.T.S will detect targets that you normally would not see.

When you are in a dangerous area, you can attempt to enter V.A.T.S to locate potential threats. Enemies that are visible, but far in the distance or partially obscured by cover, will be highlighted. So will land mines. As a result, you can be more aware of the enemy presence, and reduce the risk of being accidentally blown up by land mines. In actual fact, this is a very important feature, if you find yourself easily blown up by unnoticed mines.

This is also a useful tactic, when approaching settlements or wandering NPCs, to determine whether they are aggressive or not. Traditionally, a friendly target will be displayed in a green outline, where a hostile target will be outlined in red.

### Cinematic Combat

Providing a great sense of cinematic immersion, actions carried out in V.A.T.S. will be acted out in slow motion. Furthermore, the camera will move to different angles, to give you a better view. It will zoom in on critical hits, and will even follow the enemy, at times. In some situations, this can help you determine the actions of enemies, where they might normally be too far away to tell.

### V.A.T.S. Specific Perks

There are several perks in the game that either add function to V.A.T.S., or provide increased ability in its use. Please note that accumulative benefits only count for the shots performed within the same sequence. To ensure I noted everything, I have used the [Fallout 4 Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/), for its [page on Fallout 4 perks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perks).

- **Iron Fist**

  - (Rank 5, Strength Rank 1, Level 46): Critical hits with melee weapons are guaranteed to paralyze the target. This means that even if you do not kill the enemy, the enemy will not be able to move or attack back after the attack.
- **Awareness**

  - (Perception Rank 3): Along with displaying the targets health, damage resistances will also be displayed in V.A.T.S. to help you determine the best weapon to target the enemy with.
- **Demolition Expert**

  - (Rank 4, Perception Rank 5, Level 34): Explosives shot in V.A.T.S. explode for twice the damage. This can make shooting an enemies grenade out of their hand especially useful.
- **Sniper**

  - (Rank 3, Perception Rank 8, Level 26): Non-automatic scoped rifles have an extra 25% chance to perform head shots in V.A.T.S. making it much easier to perform high-damage shots, if you are using a sniper rifle.
- **Penetrator**

  - (Rank 1, Perception Rank 9): Enemy body parts can be targeted from V.A.T.S., even if they are behind cover. While you have a decreased hit chance, this means you an potentially perform head shots on enemies that are in cover.
  - (Rank 2, Perception Rank 9, Level 28): Upgrading this perk removes the accuracy penalty, making these shots just as deadly as regular line of sight shots.
- **Concentrated Fire**

  - (Rank 1, Perception Rank 10): Each consecutive hit on the same targeted body part gains a +10% to accuracy, in V.A.T.S. Obviously the more shots you can get off at once, the greater potential this perk can grant. But even with low agility and accuracy, this perk can back some much better odds at hitting a critical target.
  - (Rank 2, Perception Rank 10, Level 26): Increases the accuracy bonus to +15% per hit.
  - (Rank 3, Perception Rank 10, Level 50): Increases the accuracy bonus to +20% per hit, and adds an increase of +20% to damage, to sweeten the pot.
- **V.A.N.S.**

  - (Intelligence Rank 1): Holding down the V.A.T.S. button will display an in-game way point marker to the closest quest objective.
- **Quick Hands**

  - (Rank 2, Agility Rank 8, Level 28): Reloading does not cost AP. This means you do not suffer a penalty, and potentially lose a shot, if you have to reload your gun half way through performing your V.A.T.S. shots.
- **Blitz**

  - (Rank 1, Agility Rank 9): Significantly increases the range of melee attacks in V.A.T.S. allowing you to perform melee attacks without having to be as close to the enemy.
  - (Rank 2, Agility Rank 9, Level 29): Further increases the range of melee attacks in V.A.T.S., while increasing melee damage with greater distance.
- **Gun Fu**

  - (Rank 1, Agility Rank 10): Every shot past the first will deal another 25% damage.
  - (Rank 2, Agility Rank 10, Level 26): While the second shot will still receive a +25% to damage, every shot past the second will instead receive +50% to damage.
  - (Rank 3, Agility Rank 10, Level 50): Any shot past the third shot will automatically deal critical hits.
- **Mysterious Stranger**

  - (Rank 1, Luck Rank 4): A Mysterious Stranger will appear at random, to assist you in V.A.T.S. combat.
  - (Rank 2, Luck Rank 4, Level 22): Increased chance of the Mysterious Stranger appearing in V.A.T.S.
  - (Rank 3, Luck Rank 4): Increases the chance of the Mysterious Stranger appearing in V.A.T.S., but also adds a chance for Mysterious Stranger kills to fill your Critical Hit metre.
- **Critical Banker**

  - (Rank 1, Luck Rank 7): You can now store two critical hits, instead of one.
  - (Rank 2, Luck Rank 7, Level 17): You can now store three critical hits, instead of two.
  - (Rank 3, Luck Rank 7, Level 43): Not only can you store four critical hits, but filling the critical hit metre has a chance of rewarding two critical hits at once.
- **Grim Reaper's Sprint**

  - (Rank 1, Luck Rank 8): Any kill in V.A.T.S. has a 15% chance to restore all action points.
  - (Rank 2, Luck Rank 8, Level 19): Any kill in V.A.T.S. now has a 25% chance to restore all action points.
  - (Rank 3, Luck Rank 8, Level 46): Any kill in V.A.T.S. now has a 35% chance to restore all action points, and may also fill the critical hit metre.
- **Four Leaf Clover**

  - (Rank 1, Luck Rank 9): Each hit in V.A.T.S. has a chance of refilling the critical hit metre.
  - (Rank 2, Luck Rank 9, Level 32): Each hit in V.A.T.S. has an increased chance of refilling the critical hit metre.
  - (Rank 3, Luck Rank 9, Level 48): Each hit in V.A.T.S. has an even further increased chance of refilling the critical hit metre.
- **Ricochet**

  - (Rank 3, Luck Rank 10, Level 50): Any ranged attack may ricochet back at the enemy, with a chance of killing them. If this shot kills the enemy, there is a chance it will completely refill the critical hit metre.
- **Killshot** (Companion Perk, Robert MacCready): Increases the accuracy ,when targeting enemy heads in V.A.T.S., by 20%.

Comment: Don't forget the perk (cannot remember what it's called at the moment) that allows you to see specific damage resistances. That's a decently big benefit.

Comment: Considering yours is the most inclusive and upvoted answer so far, it might benefit future readers to have as much information as possible. Especially since you're even including Quest Waypoint, which you even say is "not a very useful mechanic".

Comment: Wow i wasn't aware that VATS also pointed out mines on the ground! Very handy for that since i've been paranoid about them since New Vegas. Well more specifically traps...i have a minor heart attack when suddenly something explodes unexpectedly because i set off a trap without realising!

Comment: @Slater, it's not so fun when you enter VATS and all of a sudden you hear the slow motion *beep* of a landmine and know an explosion is inevitable

Comment: @DangerZone Indeed....its why i've been exploring various buildings and whatnot REALLY slowly keeping an eye on the floor for mines or tripwires, or similar traps on the sides of safes and even looking at the rear of terminals in case they're fake explosive ones.

Comment: @Slater, I actually have not run into any terminals that do this yet. I know they were all over 3/NV though. I did run into one booby trapped trunk though (unless it was a freak coincidence explosion...)

Comment: It also allows you to see limb damage amounts, which you can't do otherwise, and to target specific limbs, which is more difficult otherwise.

Comment: I'm surprised that you haven't included "Aim assist" since that seems like the primary reason to use VATS to me. I have a friend who just doesn't do FPS. Its actually quite funny watching her try to unload an entire clip trying to kill a radroach and failing. She could not really play the game without VATS doing most of the shooting for her. I appreciate your comment on having not included things covered in answers but I think this really needs that one at least. The points you have covered seem really to be bonuses rather than the core reason for it.

Comment: Not sure if I forgot anything. Let me know

Comment: Another thing is, iirc, vats will move your cursor over your target even it wasn't before. That's a quick way to target something without moving your mouse or using the controller. Enter vats and select target, exit vats, your cursor is over the target.

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau, your link leads to the entire wiki page von vats.

Comment: It's impossible to link the needed part from the wiki directly, no anchor to use in the page. `While largely similar in Fallout 4, V.A.T.S. went through some changes. Instead of freezing time as in previous games, V.A.T.S. instead significantly slows time. Your character still benefits from a damage reduction of 90% from all incoming damage during it, as in Fallout 3. `

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau, I have added info on the damage reduction. As for the snapping, I would suggest posting your own answer to detail its value. Without overly testing it, I would have to ask how valuable V.A.T.S. targetting is for the FPS player, especially with the option of sticky aim.

Comment: I'm mostly used to Fallout 3 and used that a lot if I didn't wanted to use vats (for forgotten reason) or to quickly change target in the heat of a battle. I don't think it deserve its own answer and that's only working on my fallout 3 experience and memory. Just pointing it can be a benefit to some.

Comment: Hmm does a Laser Musket with a scope taped on count as a scoped rifle? I've hashed one together as a sniper rifle

Comment: @DangerZone There definitely are some booby-trapped trunks, and doors as well. Trunks are relatively rare, so I usually don't bother looking too closely at those. But I've gotten into the habit of carefully checking around every bathroom stall door before I open it, as those seem to be the most commonly trapped. Wherever there is a trap on a container or door, there's usually a way to spot and disable it. Of course, always keep an eye out for trip wires - physical and laser-based - as well.

Comment: @Timelord64 My background is primarily in FPS, and I'll say the aim snapping is occasionally handy. Especially so when I'm sniping, where my targets are spread out, or other cases where I need to quickly target something that's currently in my periphery or even behind me.

Comment: @Slater I don't think V.A.T.S. can spot traps. Mines, definitely. But I'm pretty sure I've never had it catch a trap or tripwire yet. Will have to double-check the next time I spot one.

Comment: I don't think there are any thrown weapons in Fallout 4. Better Criticals is also a VATS perk, since you can only get criticals in VATS.

Comment: @DCShannon, thrown weapons as in weapons you can throw. I think you might be specifically thinking of the category, as it is is other video games. In Fallout 4 there are a few thrown explosive weapons that behave as explained.

Comment: @Iszi, any trap you can shoot will appear in V.A.T.S. I delibertly address your additions in a minimal way,because they are simple to understand, and with the amount of information relative to the question, I have to account for the size of the actual answer. If you think your points deserve more focus, kindly post your own answer, instead of adding entire paragraphs to mine.

Comment: @Timelord64 Sorry, let me be clearer. I don't think there are any weapons you can throw using VATS in Fallout 4. There are grenades of course, but you don't use VATS for that.

Comment: @Timelord64 So, V.A.T.S. probably won't spot most traps then. I can't clearly recall if I've tried yet, but I'm pretty sure you can't shoot trip-wires or spring traps. Pressure plates, like scales, I'm a bit fuzzy on though.

Answer (score 14):

The V.A.T.S. system is a throwback to the old turn-based system of Fallout 1 and 2. It caters to the wishes of the players who preferred turn-based and/or are bad at FPS style fighting.

Personally, I would hate having to fight FPS style all the time, as I get motion sickness easily when I have to constantly turn around to keep the cross-hairs on the raiders circling me. Normally I play stealth and pick off my targets one by one, but when the brown stuff hits the fan, V.A.T.S. allows me to pause, re-orient myself, and get off a few close range shots that actually **hit** the target.

Comment: VATS existed in Fallout 3 and Fallout NV. And it paused game completely. In Fallout 4 it only slows time.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev - You are wrong.  VATS did not pause the game in New Vegas.

Comment: VATS most assuredly did stop time in FNV, just like in F3.

Comment: I *just* got done playing New Vegas. I think Steve may mean while the shots happen? It pauses the game completely during targetting, then when the shots are fired time does run but is slowed significantly.

Comment: It simply would not be a fallout game without VATS.

Comment: Quit letting the raiders circle you - start circle-strafing *them*!

Answer (score 8):

Vault-Tec Assisted Targeting System (VATS) allows you to slow down time and target specific parts of an enemy, target specific parts of a group of enemies, and [trigger critical hits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243963/52800). Since the game is an RPG-FPS, this caters for the fact that many players may not necessarily be FPS fans and acts as a throw back to the turn based combat of the original Fallout games.

While there is nothing stopping you from shooting the legs off a synth without VATS, VATS allows anybody to shoot the legs off a synth.

Comment: It also makes it easier to target body parts to lower accuracy (if you're being pummeled by automatic fire) or stop a cripple a swarm of ghouls by shooting some relatively weak legs off.  
Definitely beneficial when you face a tougher enemy and need to do some cripplin'

Comment: Agreed. And I find it much more useful to do than in 3 or New Vegas for some reason.

Comment: Shooting the wings off of Cazadors was one of the most useful benefits of VATS, those things are deadly if they poison you and you don't have antivenom

Answer (score 3):

V.A.T.S slows down time and allows you to select parts of the enemy to attack. If you aren't the best shot, or you are versing a fast moving enemy then it uses what is basically "turn based strategy" attacks which have a certain chance to hit (depending on the weapon you are using, the distance of the enemy etc.). It also tells you how much damage you attack is going to do to an enemy. V.A.T.S also allows you to perform special moves on enemies when using unarmed or melee weapons. It also allows you to clear a room like a badass xD

Comment: @Timelord64 No, *specific weaknesses* are seen with a special perk (energy, kinetic, etc). The predicted damage can be seen on the target's health bar as a flashing section. You'll see the amount of predicted damage rise or fall depending on the body part targeted.

Comment: +1 for it being useful against fast moving enemies. Damn Cazadors in New Vegas were awful to fight without VATS.

Answer (score 3):

While I would agree Fallout 4 has enough FPS elements to render VATS unnecessary, I still find that it provides many benefits to the user.

For one thing, I can't tell you how often I saw someone lunging at me, stopped time, aimed for their head, and killed them in midair. While this is really cool, it's also very useful.

In most FPS games, the first thing you do when you get jumped is try and aim for the assailant, and with little time to react you'll probably have to go for the chest. With VATS, all you need to do is push a single button, and in close-quarters situations you suddenly have a 95% chance of pulling off a no-scope headshot. This is similar to the optimal strategy in most game shows, which is to push the button *before* you have the answer, since you'll get a few seconds to think of it *with absolutely no threat of someone else answering first*.

I might also point out the added benefit to console gamers, who don't have as much accuracy or turning speed as someone aiming with a mouse.

Comment: I've attempted a playthrough on Very Hard with minimal VATS use, and around level 25 I started dumping stats in Agility and Luck. This almost entirely because of how much more difficult it is to deal with someone up close lunging at you without VATS, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Without V.A.T.S. I would never be able to shoot anything flying (like blood bugs), so it's easier to auto-target them. I'm also a sucker for flashy animations so naturally I love ending the fight with a critical head shot (and yelling some swear words).

It's not for everyone, but it's a fun element to the game. Like other people have said, it's also nice to look for enemies and locate land mines before you step on them :).

Answer (score -1):

VATS is a handicap and punishes those who want to play full fps.  Thats all.  I played all the orignals, and for their format of course it was (turn based) absolutely necessary.  Not so much in first person.  Its a stupid feature.  < Personal opinion.

Comment: "VATS is a handicap and punishes those who want to play full fps." Why? How? This alone make a really crappy answer.